# Does Interface Builder's new IBDesignable attribute work with NSButton and other controls in Cocoa?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I have managed to get the `IBDesignable/IBInspectable` attributes working with *direct* subclasses of `NSView` but not with a direct subclass of `NSButton`. This is causing me to question if in fact the Cocoa implementation is somehow limited to `NSView` only.

Almost every example on the web (and **Apple WWDC 2014** Xcode video) use `NSView` and then drag a custom view component from the library onto the canvas (and then change its class).

Is it possible to use `IBDesignable` with subclasses of `NSControl` and `NSButton` etc...? I have seen many examples on the web using `UIButton`.

If it is possible, then what are you supposed to drag from the library onto the canvas? It doesn't make sense for it to be a "custom view". On the other hand, there is no "custom control" available.

To be clear, I can get the IBInspectable attribute to show up at design time; but any changes don't seem to live render at design time.

The workaround is to wrap any custom `NSButton` I want to create within an `NSView` (via composition) but this seems like a bit of a hack...

Comment: Have you found some solution?

Answer (score 0):

I started playing around with a custom `NSButton` and `NSButtonCell`.

Dragging a button from the library onto the canvas and changing its class and the cell class doesn't live render. I think this is because Interface Builder still does a lot of custom things to setup `NSButtonCell`.

What works fine for me is dragging a custom view from the library onto the canvas and set its class. For this to work you need to setup the cell inside NSButtons `-initWithCoder:`.

Also I found a [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Listings/Swift_ListerKitOSX_CheckBox_swift.html) from Apple with a layer-backed custom Checkbox.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "For this to work you need to setup the cell inside NSButtons -initWithCoder:" and why this works. Recent documentation from Apple says not to touch the buttonCell so I haven't paid much attention to "cell" topics. Thanks.

Comment: Does someone have this sample? I've got an error "Sorry, that page cannot be found." =(

Comment: @catlan - the link is dead

Comment: link is dead, tried the source from Github - sampe doesn't work anymore (tried checkbox.swift and it doesn't render if added as nsbutton to storyboard). Those who look for solution - it only works with custom NSViews dragged into xib/storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to drag an `NSButton` onto the view, then set the Custom Class to your specific `NSButton` descendant. Not sure why it doesn't work when you start with an NSView.

What can give you a hint is that the `NSButton` specific attributes aren't in the "Attributes Inspector". Hence there must be some setup at the time you drag the control onto the view.